# .dat files not packaged in jar in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar, packaging

I have a maven Java project projA that build into a jar.
I have another maven Web project projB that holds a dependency of  projA.

In proj A one of my classes accesses the resources located in the packages in projA.

When I expand the jar shown under dependencies in projB, I see that it does not contain the resource files (.dat).

What setting I need to do to copy these files into the jar when I build my projA in Netbeans

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 / Java 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pom.xml, include something along the line like this:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.dat</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
[...]
```

Comment: No it did not, I added that and now it is adding the resource files in the jar. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not putting thos files into `src/main/resources`?